# signtool.exe is not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am getting the error

> Error: An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe not found.

I am using operating system window 10 and visual studio 2015

I have modified visual studio 2015, by Control Panel -> Programs and Features, find Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and select "Change"

on directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86 "signtool.exe" also showing.

But issue is not resolved same error.

Please explain me the next step

Thanks in advance

Comment: In visual studio 2015. When i rebuilt my project.

Comment: Thank you so much Arul it's working for me.